# Hiding an html Element based on Session ID

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, session

So I have these html elements on my navbar that I would like to exchange which is visible based on if a user is logged in or not, and I had created some middleware that was going to read the session id and then change the classlists added to each element, but it doesn't exactly work because the middleware script itself isn't called in the html document(at least, that is my assumption, please correct me if I am wrong.)

`

```
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item" id="navLogin">
                        <a href="./login.html" class="nav-link">
                        Login
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-hidden" id="navAccount">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            Account
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

```
export async function checkLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    const users = (await Database.get('users')) || [];

    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        const user = users[i];
        if (user.sessionID == req.session) {

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                const navLogin = document.querySelector("#navlogin");
                const navAccount = document.querySelector("#navAccount");

                navLogin.classList.add("formHidden");
                navAccount.classList.remove("formHidden");
            });
            next();
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

`

Can I fix this error by just including the file I create the middleware function on in every html page where I would call the function so that it can properly read 'document'?

I am assuming I can't so heres the next questions I have - my idea for solving this would be to have the middleware just send a variable to the html page that I would then read in js script to add/remove the class from the elements class list, but I'm not sure how to get that working. I know, or at least think that I know, that if I add

`app.get('/', (req,res) =>{ res.render({variableName: variableValue}); });` 
to the server I can send variables to the page? But I'm not sure how I would use that to read it in another js file. Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

tldr - trying to hide an html element by reading the session id, using express, nodejs.

Comment: You cannot use `document` in Node.js. A server has no direct notion of `document`. Also, it's an antipattern to define function inside a for loop. It usually leads to bugs. In your case you're uselessly attaching multiple event listeners to the `document` when actually you need only one listener. But again this seems more like you're building an Express server middleware, so, you should rethink your server logic and how/what to serve (pass data) to the frontend.

Comment: Regarding on how to send data to the frontend, read the Express server DOCS. I.e: you might want to use `res.json()` in combination with `res.sendFile()`

Comment: Another serious mistake I think you're making is the way you query the database. (Not sure what kind of DB you use or library but...) You should create a function to query the database and let the database return a `Row` or `null`. It should not be the job of your Node server function logic to go through all the `users` records in search for a `sessionID` match. Get that Row from a DB query and operate over it. No loops needed.

Comment: Another improvement based on the desired result: don't serve to the client pieces of HTML (even if CSS-hidden) if such elements should not be there in the first place. Depending on the templating rendering engine you use (if any) or framework, the server should serve to the client (browser) a HTML version with only the necessary HTML portions depending on the user being authenticated or not.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah i figured the `document` part out immediately upon trying it (that code is copied over from somewhere else in my project, I was trying to modify it for this section before i realized why it didn't work). I'm using firebase as my DB, so I'm sure there IS a way to query specifically for the specific key, but this is my first time using NoSQL instead of mySQL so I just have it this way for now. I have been looking at view engines but I'm just trying to get the basic idea of my project up and running before i make it smooth.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan with all of that said, I haven't been able to find a way to do what I've been trying to do, and none of the topics I've googled have helped. I know that there is definitely something I'm missing because websites all over the internet clearly are able to handle sending users an html page with them signed out vs them signed in, with the only visible difference being the profile pic in the top right, I just don't know what to be searching for to find it.